# SQL server select query help for stored procedure needed

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with the logic required to structure a sql select query in a stored procedure. My database works with stock market data. I have a table of trading dates for 2012, a table of ticker symbols, and a table of daily pricing data for those symbols and trade dates via a web service. I'm trying to get web service address strings written with components from my select query I'm struggling with.

The first procedure below works well enough to return records that have the fields "symbol, start date, end date" with start date and end date representing the earliest and latest missing data points that I need for each symbol:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sprocSymbsDatesForHistoricalPricingVoll

AS

DECLARE @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate date

SET @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate = dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDate()

SELECT Symbol, MIN(TradingDate), Max(TradingDate)
FROM (SELECT Symbol, TradingDate
FROM (SELECT tblSymbolsMain.Symbol, tblTradingDays.TradingDate
      FROM tblSymbolsMain CROSS JOIN
      tblTradingDays
      WHERE (tblTradingDays.TradingDate <= @NxtAvailableDataDownloadDate)) AS T1
      WHERE (NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT TradeDate, Symbol
              FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
              WHERE (TradeDate = T1.TradingDate) AND (Symbol = T1.Symbol)))) t GROUP BY Symbol ORDER BY Symbol
```

This does an ok job of cross- joining all stock symbols with all trading dates, and returning the ones that aren't in my pricing table. Fine. My problem is, while I may get back a row that gives me the min and max dates from that table per symbol that I need as such:

```
AAPL, 1/1/12, 1/10/12
```

I might already have in my pricing table some of the required data points within that date range, such as:

```
AAPL, 1/5/12- 1/9/12
```

What I would like to get back in this case would be:

```
AAPL, 1/1/12, 1/4/12
AAPL, 1/10/12, 1/10/12
```

Instead of the first example with stock symbol above. I could do this easily by looping in a procedural code fashion but I'd like to see this implemented on the db side. Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is your answer.  Here's how you can take your inner select statement and transform it into range rows. Recursion is available in SQL 2005 or above so I hope that works for you.

```
create table dates (dt datetime  null)
go
insert into dates(dt) values('1/1/2012')
insert into dates(dt) values('1/2/2012')
insert into dates(dt) values('1/3/2012')
insert into dates(dt) values('1/4/2012')
insert into dates(dt) values('1/10/2012')
go

--Show raw data
select * from dates
go

--Define the recursive query
WITH RecursiveQuery (anchorDate, dt)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member of recursive query
    SELECT 
        anchorDate=dt,
        dt
    FROM 
        dates AS e
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(select 1 from dates where dateadd(day,-1,e.dt)=dt)
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member (notice join to RecursiveQuery)
    SELECT 
        anchorDate=d.anchorDate,
        e.dt
    FROM 
        dates AS e
        INNER JOIN RecursiveQuery AS d ON e.dt = dateadd(day,1,d.dt)
)

--Final Join
select 
    startdt=anchorDate,enddt=max(dt) 
FROM 
    RecursiveQuery 
group by anchorDate
order by anchorDate
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it.. I'm new to recursion in sql, but I'll try to implement that. I had a feeling a "typical" select statement just wouldn't do it. Thanks.