# SQL Server recursive cte help wanted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I'm trying to generate a data set, and I think recursion is required, but I can't quite adapt the numerous examples I've found to my purposes. The end result I want is fairly simple to describe.

Two tables are involved: the first with trading pricing for stocks with the relevant fields `TradeDate`, `Symbol`, and `Clse` (closing price), and a table with trading days listed. I'd like to partition the pricing data by symbol, ordered by date, but I'd like the partition/ row numbering to break if a trade date is missing from the pricing table, since this data comes in from a web service that is a little unpredictable at times.

My first attempt was a simple enough select query that had a `WHERE` clause that called a udf I wrote to see if there was continuous data for that symbol/ date combination. It worked (it ran) and the night I ran it, after 7 hours it was almost through the symbols starting with 'A.'

**EDIT**:
This post of mine and the response a little while back [SQL server select query help for stored procedure needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170857/sql-server-select-query-help-for-stored-procedure-needed) on SO was helpful conceptually, but my current use of the concept requires a little more (table join, partitioning/ row numbering etc)

If it helps understand the problem, I want to use what's returned to calculate various aggregations per symbol, trade date combination that use the past data points. Example: 5 period moving average of closing price for a symbol/ trade date would be the average of the five closing prices (clse) that have a trade date <= the date being calculated for. So using the sample data below from the first table, I want to return 9.02 for symbol 'A', 3 periods, trade date 1/3/12. If data is missing for one of the calculations I want null.

This result set I want would be a simple PARTITION select query if it weren't for having to check for missing dates. So here is some sample data of the tables involved and my goal result set:

**tblDailyPricingAndVol**

```
TradeDate Symbol Clse
1/1/12    A      9.01
1/2/12    A      9.05
1/3/12    A      8.99
1/5/12    A      9.03
1/1/12    B      10.05
1/4/12    B      10.11
1/5/12    B      10.03
```

**tblTradingDays**

```
TradingDate
1/1/12
1/2/12
1/3/12
1/4/12
1/5/12
```

Goal result set:

```
RowNumber TradeDate Symbol Clse
1         1/1/12    A      9.01
2         1/2/12    A      9.05
3         1/3/12    A      8.99
1         1/5/12    A      9.03
1         1/1/12    B      10.05
1         1/4/12    B      10.11
2         1/5/12    B      10.03
```

Hope that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated. I think I'll see recursive cte's much more clearly if I can get one running as expected on my own data. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think a recursive CTE would help here. What you would be needing is the `lag` windowing function. But SQL Server does not yet support that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Really? Maybe I do have a good grasp on recursive cte's then because I don't see how it would work in this application. I haven't heard of lag. Maybe I need a cursor and a more procedural- code type stored procedure.

Comment: `lag` is a standard windowing function that let's you access the column values of previous rows.

Comment: You could partition by `Symbol` - but then you'd get `1, 2, 3, 4` for symbol `A` - the row number doesn't restart in the middle of a partition. Or you could partition by `Symbol, TradeDate` - but then you'd get consecutive numbering for each date. Your requirement is really quite hard (if not impossible) to fulfill with T-SQL

Comment: @marc_s That's exactly where I'm at... easy to partition as I'd like it, if it weren't necessary to deal with missing data points. I'm going to edit my post to describe what I want to use the result set for. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think combining `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` will work here:

```
; with cte as (
    select d.TradingDate,p.Symbol,p.Clse
    , r=DENSE_RANK()over(order by d.TradingDate)
    , r1=row_number()over(partition by p.Symbol order by p.TradeDate)
    from tblTradingDays d
    inner join tblDailyPricingAndVol p on d.TradingDate=p.TradeDate
)
select
RowNumber=row_number()over(partition by Symbol, (r-r1) order by TradingDate)
, TradingDate,Symbol,Clse
from cte
go
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That did it. I was just about to look at pulling data into C# and handling the logic there. Fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
set dateformat mdy

declare @tblDailyPricingAndVol table
(
  TradeDate date,
  Symbol char(1),
  Clse money
)

insert into @tblDailyPricingAndVol values
('1/1/12',    'A',      9.01),
('1/2/12',    'A',      9.05),
('1/3/12',    'A',      8.99),
('1/5/12',    'A',      9.03),
('1/1/12',    'B',      10.05),
('1/4/12',    'B',      10.11),
('1/5/12',    'B',      10.03)

;with C as
(
  select TradeDate,
         Symbol,
         Clse,
         row_number() over(partition by Symbol order by TradeDate) as rn
  from @tblDailyPricingAndVol
)
select row_number() over(partition by Symbol, datediff(day, 0, TradeDate) - rn 
                         order by TradeDate) as RowNumber,
       TradeDate,
       Symbol,
       Clse
from C
order by Symbol, TradeDate
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well, I'll be experimenting with both solutions.