# SQL Server dense rank/ inner join conceptual clarification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join, dense-rank

I'm hoping to gain clarity on the behavior of the dense rank function when working with joins. I got a great solution to a post of mine earlier here [SQL Server recursive cte help wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555354/sql-server-recursive-cte-help-wanted) In looking at the solution, which involves using dense rank along with an inner join to partition data with breaks at missing data points.

So: Based on how I read the solution, when in an inner join, dense rank includes in its ranking rows that are on the left side, but not on the right. I set up a small test of this, and I can't reproduce that behavior. For example, when I run the query and I use a basic select statement on the cte, without partitioning it again as it is in the original query, and the data point for 1/5/12, A is missing, I get:

```
TradeDate     Symbol Clse   DenseRank RowNumber
2012-01-03    A      36.48  1     1
2012-01-04    A      36.19  2     2
2012-01-06    A      37.40  4     3
```

Based on my current understanding, the dense rank value above would just go from 2 to 3 on the last two records, since the join doesn't return a match for the date in tblDailyPricingAndVol. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your previous example, `tblTradingDays` have 1 to many relationship to `tblDailyPricingAndVol`.

All dates in `tblDailyPricingAndVol` exists in `tblTradingDays`.

Thus the join in your previous example doesn't eliminate any records

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how that other query works. the `dense_rank` value is not used in the join. It is used in the partition clause `(r-r1)` to create a group for consecutive dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK` will rank the **result** of the join. Since you don't have `2012-01-02` in `Table2` the result is two rows and `DENSE_RANK` will give the the ranking values `1` and `2`.

Comment: Thanks... what I'm not seeing at the moment is that in the example I provided the link for, it seems that the missing date values are calculated in the rank, which is visible if you display the cte results without partitioning again. I'll update my post..