# How to query nested members in LDAP through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ldap

I want to query all the members in a team through manager's name. For example, if managerA has two direct reports: managerB and employee1. And managerB has two direct reports: employee2 and employee3. I want to get all the members in managerA's team: managerB, employee1, employee2 and employee3.

If I use below query, I only could get the members: managerB and employee1. How can I query nested members? Thanks!

```
Select * from openquery
(
      ADSI,'Select CN from ''LDAP://mydomain.com''
      WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass = ''user''
      AND manager = ''CN=managerA,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com''
      order by CN
');
```

Comment: The ADO interface available in SQL Server is **very limited** and does not allow to do advanced queries like getting nested members and stuff like that.

Comment: oh...so any suggestions?

Comment: Not really - basically you'll just have to handle it yourself, querying AD multiple times ....

Answer (score 0):

If it's inexpensive (and makes sense!)  to pull your LDAP data into SQLServer maybe you could do that first and then run a recursive query in SQLServer. That would actually be perfect for what you're trying to accomplish. I answered another recursion question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170857/sql-server-select-query-help-for-stored-procedure-needed/9173040#9173040) if you need a sample for some ideas.